# How to create a new table by Joining Two Different Databases based on a unique ID using SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have two databases, one in an MySQL instance and another in an Microsoft SQL Server instance.

In the MySQL database I have a table called `users` a unique ID, that can be linked up to various tables.

On the Microsoft SQL Serve database I have a table that contains the user info that I would like to perform a `JOIN` to, based on the unique ID. For example, the user purchases and then create a new table Microsoft SQL Server based on the joined data.

If anyone could give me a clear step on how to go about it, or a tutorial link on the same, I'd much appreciate it as am still stuck on whether
to use ADO NET source or ODBC connections on the 1st step.

Comment: Hi @Didi for my projects I am using ODBC for MYSQL and OLE DB for MSSQL.

Comment: *"If anyone could give me a clear step on how to go about it, or a tutorial link on the same, I'd much appreciate it as am still stuck on whether"* SO isn't for tutorial, article, and resource recommendations. You need to ask a programming based question which is after a programming based solution. Show us what you've tried, and explain why it didn't work. Or show us the research you performed and tell us what you didn't understand so we can try to elaborate on it.

Comment: SSIS is an ETL tool, it doesn't generate joins between tables. You haven't explained what you try to do, so one can only guess. You can use a Lookup transformation to load lookup data from one database while loading the main data from another database. If you want to load data that has just a `UserID` for example, you can use a `Lookup` transformation to look up the user name etc and add the relevant columns to the data you insert to the target database

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an OLEDB provider, so you'll have to install and use an ODBC or ADO.NET provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my main issue was deciding on which connectors to use for the data sources and destinations.

I found this page that clearly spells them out.

Hope it helps someone.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1947.ssis-and-data-sources.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Create two REST API one for MYSQL table, and another for SQL SERVER.
Using Linq we can join the two tables in any of the api's

Comment: REST APIs offer nothing in this case and LINQ doesn't work with raw HTTP anyway and finally there's no "REST APIs", REST is a style that has nothing to do with querying. Databases have common APIs for decades now - in fact more than one: ODBC, OLEDB, JDBC and more